# Reuse same view in list and detail ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, model-view-controller, mobile

I have common List-Detail app. TableView for displaying the index of Items and detail ViewController showing single item with more details.

```
List:

+-----------------+
|                 |
|     IMAGE 1     |
|                 |
+-----------------+
|button1  button2 |
|=================|
|                 |
|     IMAGE 2     |
|                 |
+-----------------+
|button1  button2 |
|=================|
|        .        |
|        .        |
|        .        |


Detail:
+-----------------+
|                 |
|     IMAGE 1     |
|                 |
+-----------------+
| some text       |
+-----------------+
|button1  button2 |  <= same actions/handlers as in list
|=================|
```

Both have a button bar with multiple buttons (like, save, etc). How to reuse the logic of this button bar?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add those functions (save, like etc) to the class that contains the data (image, text etc). You can then call the function from anywhere you want and it will do the same. For example:

```
class Post {
    var image: UIImage?
    var text: String?

    func save() {
        // Put your code here to save the 'Post'
    }

    func like() {
        // Put your code here to like the 'Post'
    }
}
```

For your custom `UIView` and `UITableViewCell` you can do a similar thing by using a `protocol` and `extension`. For example:

```
protocol UpdateState {
    var myImageView: UIImageView? { get }
    var myTextLabel: UILabel? { get }
    func save()
    func like()
}

extension UpdateState {

    func save() {
        // Put your code here to save the 'Post'
        myTextLabel?.text = "New text after save"
        myImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "SavedImage")
    }

    func like() {
        // Put your code here to like the 'Post'
        myTextLabel?.text = "New text after like"
        myImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "NewImage")
    }
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell, UpdateState {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView?

    // This is here to conform to the UpdateState protocol
    var myTextLabel: UILabel? = nil
}

class View: UIView, UpdateState {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextLabel: UILabel?
}
```

Comment: this is what i actually do, but there is much more same code, like animation or ui state changes.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can share code between a UIView and a UITableViewCell. Hope this makes sense in your case.

Comment: looks like the views act as controllers. This is what I want to avoid ...

Comment: No, your view controllers call a function on the cell/view. So in your view controller you have another 'save' function which will call the save functions on the cell/view and on the post object.

Comment: But depending on what 'other' code you want to execute, you could use a similar structure for your view controllers instead of for the cell/view.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate button bar components in which you set the datasource, If you are sure that at particular index you want to show particular number of buttons, then make a dictionary as data source, key will be index and value will be another dictionary storing the title for the button. And you can read the datasource and programatically can create buttons in separate button bar components